# Multiple 500 errors when google caliper tries to upload benchmark results to microbenchmarks.appspot.com

Tags: java, microbenchmark, caliper

I'm seeing multiple `HTTP 500` errors when `Caliper` tries to upload the JSON result files for the benchmarks I'm running. The logs are filled with exceptions similar to the one below:

```java
Dec 19, 2013 3:29:20 PM com.google.caliper.runner.ResultsUploader logUploadFailure
SEVERE: Could not upload trial c0e4f478-7408-4050-88d3-7446e21bb7a1. Consider uploading it manually.
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/data/trials?key={my-valid-api-key} returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:697)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$400(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:548)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ResultsUploader.processTrial(ResultsUploader.java:104)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.ExperimentingCaliperRun.run(ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:231)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain.exitlessMain(CaliperMain.java:135)
    at com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain.main(CaliperMain.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

However, a report does show up on the `/runs` page under my account, so it seems it's able to upload at least some of them. Doing a `curl POST` to the specified URL with any of the failed trials results in the same error.

Has anyone else encountered these errors? Is there something I'm missing in my configuration?

Caliper `config.properties`:

```
# Caliper config file
# Run with --print-config to see all of the options being applied

# INSTRUMENT CONFIG
# instrument.micro.options.warmup=10s
# instrument.micro.options.timingInterval=500ms
# instrument.micro.options.reportedIntervals=7
# instrument.micro.options.maxRuntime=10s

# VM CONFIG
vm.args=-Xmx3g -Xms3g

# See the Caliper webapp to get a key so you can associate results with your account
results.upload.options.key={my-valid-api-key}
```

Caliper version:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.caliper</groupId>
        <artifactId>caliper</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

System properties:

```properties
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 08:22:22-0700)
Maven home: ~/maven3/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Also, the error logs suggest uploading the failed results manually. However, I don't see any option on the [Microbenchmarks Appspot page](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com) to *upload* results.

Edit 1:
Benchmark launch command:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain" -Dexec.args="my.benchmarkclass"
```

Comment: I just went and looked at the server-side logs and there appears to be an issue in the persistence layer that's causing issues.  https://code.google.com/p/caliper/issues/detail?id=282 has been filed and the issue will be addressed shortly.  Sorry about that.

Comment: As noted on the bug, the size limit has been increased in a few places.  Hopefully, your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! I ran the tests again now and did not see any upload errors this time. Btw, is there a plan to open source the `Microbenchmarking Appspot app` as well? It would be nice to host it locally!